# rails : association :undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

A 'page' may have_many 'sections'. So I want to retrieve the 'sections.title' for each 'sections' that a page contains. I don't understand why my block `Do` doesn't work but this works `sections.each { |n| p n.id }`

```
2.0.0-p353 :041 > pages = Page.find(52).sections.count
Page Load (0.3ms) SELECT `pages`.* FROM `pages` WHERE `pages`.`id` = 52 LIMIT 1
(0.3ms) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sections` WHERE `sections`.`page_id` = 52
=> 2
2.0.0-p353 :042 > pages =Page.find(52).sections
Page Load (0.3ms) SELECT `pages`.* FROM `pages` WHERE `pages`.`id` = 52 LIMIT 1
Section Load (0.2ms) SELECT `sections`.* FROM `sections` WHERE `sections`.`page_id` = 52
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Section id: 20, title: "La victoire est proche", body: "Guinsly t'e le meilleur Oat cake sweet roll browni...", page_id: 52, created_at: "2014-01-22 01:40:14", updated_at: "2014-01-22 01:40:14">, #<Section id: 36, title: "La victoire est proche", body: "Guinsly t'e le meilleur Oat cake sweet roll browni...", page_id: 52, created_at: "2014-01-22 01:40:15", updated_at: "2014-01-22 01:40:15">]>
2.0.0-p353 :044 > pages.each do |n|
2.0.0-p353 :045 > p.title
2.0.0-p353 :046?> end
NoMethodError: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

or
...
2.0.0-p353 :055 > Page.find(52).sections.each { |n| p n.id }
Page Load (0.3ms) SELECT `pages`.* FROM `pages` WHERE `pages`.`id` = 52 LIMIT 1
Section Load (0.3ms) SELECT `sections`.* FROM `sections` WHERE `sections`.`page_id` = 52
20
36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your each block is looking for you to use `n` not `p`...

```
pages.each do |n|
  n.title
end
```

Though `p` makes more sense, you might use `p` instead of `n` in both places.

Or are you trying to print the value using the `p` method?  Then:

```
pages.each do |page|
  p page.title
end
```

Comment: thks! Hellios! I didn't noticed the p :(.